# Calling show() method in spreadsheet by trigger / doPost

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a spreadsheet respond to incoming doPost(e) request, by presenting a user interface.

I do get a server error when I do that with the published script. (call ss.show(userinterface)

Is this possible to do anyway?﻿

I just want to get a notification when data us pushed to the spreadsheet using an external applicatoin. Adding a row is okay, but I would like to trigger the Htmlservice popup to give information about that data.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible to show ui from there, only from an interface created from doGet and responding to browser events from the user that created it.
You have some options:
1 keep open a sidebar that regularly polls the status (from a script property for example every 10s).
2 i havent tried this from a post, but try doing ss.toast("cheers"). Doubt would work thou